# Can I hide the domain name in the URL (in my Rails application)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Ruby on Rails application where my customers should ask their customers to go. But I would like to be able to hide/mask my own domain name from the url, so the customers of my customers don't feel like they are on a 3rd party website.

For example, if my domain name is:

```
https://app.example.com/visit/:customer_id
```

then what is my options for masking the `example.com` part?

If it is not possible to mask the domain name (I can see that even by using the IP address directly, https errors appear), then is it possible to put in some prefixes like e.g.:

```
https://prefix.app.example.com/visit/:customer_id
https://app.prefix.example.com/visit/:customer_id
https://app.example.prefix.com/visit/:customer_id
```

Btw, it's not important to keep the https security on these pages particularly, but I don't suppose it is possible to have an application that has both encrypted and non-encrypted pages?

Comment: Of course apps can have HTTP and HTTPS pages. You can't "mask" the host, but you can point multiple domain names at your host etc, although your app has to be set up to handle multi-tenancy somehow.

Comment: Do you want to prevent the URLs to be displayed in the URL bar or in the status bar when hovering a link?

Comment: @lassej The URL bar is the most important.

Comment: Then your customers should probably embed your site with an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your customers will have to setup their DNS to point to your application. you can use a [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) to accomplish that. this can be done by using a subdomain.

if you use SSL/HTTPS you have to make sure that the certificates match the domain.

like @lassej already pointed out, an iframe is probably a better way of integration. it has several limitations though.